# Scraping interactive graph into data table with R

Tags: r

I was looking to scrape the first interactive graph from this website link: https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/china/beijing/historic?month=5&year=2014

I intend to scrap the data within the interactive graph into a table format. I tried to inspect the page to implement JSTOR but i can't seem to figure it out.

Was wondering if anyone could help with the coding aspect in R. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you take the data from the table below? Seems much easier

Comment: I thought of extracting the html table instead, however, i am unaware of how to extract multiple tables as I would require every single day for the year and the url doesn't change when i change the input in the dropdown box

Comment: Try using `RSelenium` to extract the table below graph.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Developer Mode in Firefox, you can see the GET request that is made when you switch to another date:

https://www.timeanddate.com/scripts/cityajax.php?n=china/beijing&mode=historic&hd=20140514&month=5&year=2014&json=1

Based on that you can write a script that makes this request for each day you need (in the following example I used the interval from 2014-12-24 to 2015-01-06).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr2)
library(glue)
library(lubridate)

days <- seq(ymd("2014-12-24"), # Set the days to be queried
            ymd("2015-01-06"), 
            by = "days") |> 
  set_names()

pad <- partial(str_pad, width = 2, pad = 0)

# prep request for each day
req <- map(days, 
    ~ glue("https://www.timeanddate.com/scripts/cityajax.php?n=china/beijing&mode=historic",
           "&month={month(.x)}", 
           "&year={year(.x)}", 
           "&hd={year(.x)}{pad(month(.x))}{pad(day(.x))}") |> 
      request())

resp <- map(req, req_perform) # actual request is performed
```

```r
# Cleaning the returned data 
d <- map(
  resp,
  ~ .x %>%
    .["body"] |>
    read_lines(progress = F) %>%
    str_c("<table>", ., "</table>") |>
    read_html() |>
    html_table() %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    .[-2] %>%
    set_names(.[1,]) |>
    janitor::clean_names() %>%
    slice(-1,-nrow(.)) %>%
    mutate(time = str_extract(time, "^\\d{2}:\\d{2}"))
  ) |> 
  bind_rows(.id = "date")

d
#> # A tibble: 112 × 9
#>    date       time  temp  weather  wind   x     humidity barometer visibility
#>    <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     
#>  1 2014-12-24 02:00 4 °C  Haze.    4 km/h ↑     18%      1027 mbar 30 km     
#>  2 2014-12-24 05:00 2 °C  Haze.    9 km/h ↑     22%      1029 mbar 30 km     
#>  3 2014-12-24 08:00 1 °C  Sunny.   6 km/h ↑     26%      1032 mbar 27 km     
#>  4 2014-12-24 11:00 3 °C  Sunny.   7 km/h ↑     24%      1034 mbar 20 km     
#>  5 2014-12-24 14:00 5 °C  Sunny.   7 km/h ↑     22%      1032 mbar 22 km     
#>  6 2014-12-24 17:00 4 °C  Clear.   6 km/h ↑     23%      1032 mbar 19 km     
#>  7 2014-12-24 20:00 2 °C  Clear.   4 km/h ↑     28%      1033 mbar 16 km     
#>  8 2014-12-24 23:00 0 °C  Ice fog. 2 km/h ↑     36%      1034 mbar 4 km      
#>  9 2014-12-25 02:00 -2 °C Ice fog. 2 km/h ↑     50%      1034 mbar 5 km      
#> 10 2014-12-25 05:00 -2 °C Ice fog. 4 km/h ↑     51%      1034 mbar 9 km      
#> # … with 102 more rows
```